# using(s) inside a loop with a continue

Tags: c#, performance, while-loop, idisposable, continue

Given the following sample code:

```
var count = 0;
while (count < 5)
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
    using (var response = await StaticHttpClient.Client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            switch ((int)response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 500:
                case 504:
                    continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {  ... }
    }

    count++;
}
```

Will those IDisposable objects leak memory in this method or will the Dispose method be properly called?  (There are many cases missing from the switch and I'm not concerned about the efficiency there).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will those IDisposable objects leak memory in this method or will the Dispose method be properly called?

The disposables will get `Dispose()` called on them properly since you used a `using` statement.  When you `continue`, the `Dispose()` methods will be called prior to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Excellent.  That was the functionality I expected, however I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking myself the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Using statement will always call Dispose() this is the whole point of using it